# How do I get diffs from two branches as a single commit and make it a new branch?

Tags: git

I have two branches called `develop` and `feature`, they both have lots of commits. Is there a way that I can make a branch called `diff` that it's based on `develop` and has a single commit that makes contents of `develop` looks exactly like `feature`?

Basically `diff` and `feature` has the same content but it has a single commit that turns `develop` looks like `feature`.

- Before

```
feature - B - D - F - G
             /
develop A - C - E
```

- After

```
feature - B - D - F - G
             /
develop A - C - E - - -
                        \
diff                     H
```

`G` and `H` has same content so I can get rid of `feature` completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout -b diff feature
git reset --soft develop
git commit
```

or

```
git checkout -b diff develop
git read-tree -um feature
git commit
```

will do it.

Are you aware that what you're asking for will also revert the changes in `E`?

Comment: Yes, I just want a commit that make current HEAD of `develop` looks like `feature`, reverting `E` is expected. And it worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but why don't you just do

```
git checkout develop
git pull origin feature
git checkout -b diff
```

Comment: Thanks, this was my original plan. But what I wanted is to see all the diffs from one branch to another as a single commit, so I can see what is changed and modify if necessary. I also want to erase all the commit history of `feature` since it's quite old that bad for history-tracking.

Comment: This `pull` does two things that are not asked for: (1) it keeps the changes in `E` (does not make `diff` equal to `feature`) and (2) it changes `develop`. (2) can be fixed by making branch `diff` before the `pull`, but (1) can only be fixed by not using `pull`. See the other answer.